# Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Container\ContainerInterface' not found in

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Two weeks ago I didn't have any problem, but today this appears when I put composer install

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>
> Nothing to install or update
>
> Generating optimized autoload files
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Psr\Container\ContainerInterface' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/nuevodirectorio/ClinicaLaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Container/Container.php on line 8
>
> Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Container\ContainerInterface' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/nuevodirectorio/ClinicaLaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Container/Container.php on line 8

Here is part of the code of Container.php:

```
<?php
  namespace Illuminate\Container;

  use Closure;
  use Exception;
  use ArrayAccess;
  use LogicException;
  use ReflectionClass;
  use ReflectionParameter;
  use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container as ContainerContract;

  class Container implements ArrayAccess, ContainerContract
  {
   ...
  }
```

Comment: That is not the file causing the problem. I'd suggest just reinstalling everything with `rm composer.lock && composer install`

Answer (score 6):

At my job we had the same problem. In our case, there was a psr/container file causing a conflict, but this file was in the composer global cache, so removing the vendor folder alone didn't help us. First we needed to clear the composer cache using this command:

```
composer clearcache
```

and then we removed the vendor folder and ran composer install, everything went fine. I hope this solution helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was deleting the vendor directory as well as the composer.lock file then reinstalling dependencies afresh.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Still investigating, but what I discovered so far is that, running `composer install --no-dev [...]`, I have the package `psr/container` in `vendor/psr/container` in vendors, but `'Psr\\Container\\' => array($vendorDir . '/psr/container/src'),` line missing in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`.

For the time being, I fixed it including dev dependencies, until I figure out the real fix.